# C# sending mail with gmail account works locally but not online

Tags: c#, .net-core, gmail, smtpclient

I have a .net core application with an email client.
Locally works everything perfectly, the mail is sent with attachment, but when I deploy my API, I always receive the same error when I try to send an email.

This is my code. The api received all my settings from the app setting file.

```
 cigarMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;

            var mailClient = new SmtpClient(_config.GetValue<string>("SMTPHost"), _config.GetValue<int>("SMTPPort"))
            {
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials =
                new NetworkCredential("rokokoen@gmail.com", _config.GetValue<string>("PasswordSender")),
                EnableSsl = true
            };

            writer.Write(orderPdf);
            writer.Flush();
            
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            var attachment = new Attachment(new MemoryStream(orderPdf), "Bestelling-bvbaRomboutEdiers.pdf", System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
            cigarMsg.Attachments.Add(attachment);

            try
            {
                mailClient.Send(cigarMsg);
                memoryStream.Dispose();
                writer.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Log.Error(e, "Host terminated unexpectedly.");
                throw;
            }
```

The appsetting of my API

[image]

I know SMTPPort should be an int, but I convert the type to int, as you can see in my code.
Yes, this is working locally.

I also searched on previous Stackoverflow questions, but nothing worked.
I tried everything on the other stack overflow questions, but nothing helped.

The error I received is:

[image]

That is the error when I try to execute the send mail method.

Is there anyone who can help me with this problem?

Comment: Is it the same PC? If not, what version of TLS does the other PC allow?

Comment: I assume you are using the same email account when it works and doesn't work.  The error that indicates you are not making a connection to the mail server.  So when you deploy the application you are on a network that isn't allowing the connection to complete.  With SMTP many companies with a email server use Port Forwarding to forward all emails to a Proxy Server.  The forwarding is done at a firewall that checks the port number of all TCP messages and redirects the messages to the proxy.  Your code will not work with the online network.

Comment: Yes correct, using the same account local and online, also on the same pc.

Answer (score 1):

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated.  The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required:

Solutions in order of likely hood to help.

1. Check if the user has 2fa enabled if so you will need an [apps password](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en)
2. Check your [Captcha loc](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)
3. Look into [Xoauth2](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently working with a Gmail account is a lot harder than a Hotmail account.
So I switched my SMTP host and port.

Sending emails is now working.

Thanks for the help.